# want original static files to get downloaded from server

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

I have enabled gzip compression in IIS. While downloading .xlsx files from server in IE browser, the files are getting compressed.
When I am disabling static content compression in IIS, I am not getting original size of the files.

Is there any setting on IIS7/root config level, where I can make changes to get .xlsx files in its original form, without affecting any other components.

Answer (score 0):

By default i don't think IIS enables compression for ms-office documents. But it could be a case in your server if it's configured like that.

> Is there any setting on IIS7/root config level, where I can make
>   changes to get .xlsx files in its original form, without affecting any
>   other components

**I assume your question is to get excel files without compression?**

Yes IIS has a `ApplicationHost.Config` that you can use. This is at the root level(*Be doubly sure before doing this might affect other hosted apps*). In this, Navigate to element `staticTypes` under `httpCompression` element. If the following are `enabled`, disable them by making them to `false`. It will disable '`*.xlsx`','`*.xls`' respectively.

```
<add mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" enabled="false"/>
<add mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" enabled="false"/>
```

Help urls

configuring static types - http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression/statictypes

mime-mapping - http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-can-i-define-mime-types-on-my-windowsiis-based-site

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Sridhar.
but I dont have httpcompression element in root config.
But, I do have "<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />".
I can see .xlsx MIME type in IIS 7 for my site.
Can i delete that or should I add the above given line of code?

Comment: can you update the question with wat you are seeing?

Comment: I don't have httpcompression element in root config. But, I do have "<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />". 
When I doble clicked on MIME type in IIS 7, I can see .xlsx MIME type for my site. Shall I delete that or should I add the above given lines of code in root config under <static content> element?

Comment: it's not staticContent it's staticTypes... search for that

Comment: There is no statictypes element in root config of my site.
I have staticcontent and urlcompression elements..
Pls let me know, where should i change settings?

Comment: @Kapil which config file are you looking at?. `ApplicationHost.config` that i mentioned will be in this path '`%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config`'. please check there.. it would be tough for me to help unless you update the question with the config file snippet that you see.